# fastboot flash system fail: Writing 'system' FAILED (remote: 'Malloc failed for: CHUNK_TYPE_FILL')

Tags: chunks, fastboot

In Android Q, is P OTA to Q version with 512M of memory. I reported the following error during execution.

> fastboot flash system P_2_Q\aosp_arm-img-6161928\system.img
>   Header magic invalid sparse file format
>   Sending Sparse "System" 1/52 (16380 KB) OKAY [0.545s]
>   Writing to "System" failed (Remote: "***Malloc failed: CHUNK_TYPE_FILL***")
>   fastboot: error: command failed

Does anyone know what is causing this?